# Error: Cannot find module "." mongodb with webpack and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, webpack

I have a problem when I can use mongoose with webpack. I already installed it as a dependency but when I want to use the mongoose object and execute it it commands me that it can not find the "." Module. And that seems very strange, I've been looking for a good time, I installed the dependencies again, delete the npm cache, reinstall webpack

I would appreciate your support, thank you very much

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

var typescriptLoader = {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader'
};

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.ts",
    target: "node",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "dist/",
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    node: {
        __filename: true,
        __dirname: true
    },
    watch: true,
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public_html"),
        watchContentBase: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [ typescriptLoader ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ]
    },
    externals: {

    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js -p",
    "start": "node dist/main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.39",
    "@types/helmet": "0.0.34",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.10",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.11",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cheerio": "^0.22.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "helmet": "^3.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.4",
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import * as mongoose     from 'mongoose'; // ALL OK

console.log(mongoose); // Error when is used
```

Error

```
var n;n="undefined"==typeof window?!function(){var e=new Error('Cannot find module "."');throw e.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",e}():r(204),/*!
                                                                                             ^
Error: Cannot find module "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoose is npm module. TypeScript may not recognized the way you import it. try the nodejs require module loading system.

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
```

or

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem. What happens is that when the webpack packages all the dependencies for some reason does not include mongoose and in any case should say **"Could not load the module: mongoose"** instead of that says **"Could not load the module: ."** it is very weird